# Subdivision Surface Problem

Tags: modeling

I have a soldier model:
[image: https://i.ibb.co/nMsgTfJ/before.png]

When I add the *Subdivision Surface* modifier, this happens to the model:
[image]

Does anyone know how to remove this?
I just wanted to add smoothness to the models, but not that.

Comment: The model appears to be split into individual faces. Go into edit mode, select everything with [A], press [ALT] + [M], then By Distance to remove doubled vertices. If that model wasn't made to handle subdivision surface though, you will likely not get an ideal result.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: If your using 2.79 (like me and my boomer friends(lol)) then the short cut for remove doubles is [w].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The split faces subdivided look a lot like what a quad would if subdivided. Thus as @Rekov already mentioned, you should be fine after doing the following:

1. Deactivate the Subdivision Surface Modifier (faster depending on the model)
2. Go in Edit Mode
3. Select all elements of the object with <kbd>A</kbd>, either mode, vertices, edges or faces will work
4. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and select "Merge by Distance"
5. Go in Object Mode and if you did not do yet, <kbd>RMB</kbd> Shade Smooth
6. Activate the Subdivision Surface Modifier again
7. Smile

Happy blending.

Comment: I am so happy! Thanks you!

Comment: May i ask you to accept the answer as solved if it did solve your question.